# Need to get client id of each user from azure portal and want to store in a variable using php

Tags: php, azure, rest

I need to make the code that will check the resources of their azure portal.
For example user a logins the this API will hit GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?api-version=2021-04-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resources?api-version=2021-04-01)

and the ***subscription ID*** will pass automatically of user a.
How do I authenticate the user?
How do I get their subscription ID in PHP code? So every user will be able to fetch their resources details on the website by simply login.
What should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Azure REST API to list subscriptions.  NOTE: a user may have more than one subscription under the current tenant and it will return all subscriptions that user has access to.

#### REST GET Subscriptions

`GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list

#### Rest API reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign in to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/).
2. Under the Azure services heading, select Subscriptions. (If no subscriptions are listed, you may need to switch Azure AD tenants.) Your Subscription IDs are listed in the second column.
3. Copy the Subscription ID and paste it into a text document of your choice for use later.

Comment: Hi buddy, I need to fetch the subscription Id from Azure after user login in my web application and the I will put the subscription id or client id in the API so first task is to authenticate the user with his azure portal and store the client key value r subscription value in one variable and then he/she can able to fetch the details from API